# Javascript audio loop repeat every 15 seconds

Tags: javascript, loops, audio, settimeout, background-music

As above, I have a function that repeats a sound but has no pause in between. I would like the audio to open every 15 seconds.

```
 function handleLoad(event) {
    createjs.Sound.play("pain");
     var myInstance = createjs.Sound.play("pain", {interrupt: createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_ANY, loop:-1});
 }

handleLoad();
```

Thank you.

I tried to use setTimeOut but i guess i wrote it wrong.

```
 var myInstance = setTimeout(createjs.Sound.play("pain", {interrupt: createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_ANY, loop:-1}),15000);
```

Comment: Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) and you need to pass a function as an argument: `setInterval(handleLoad, 15000)`

Comment: Well, 


`const myInterval = setInterval(handleLoad, 15000)

 function handleLoad(event) {
 createjs.Sound.play("pain");
 } ` And `clearInterval(myInterval);`  this to clear. Thanks!